# How to create a user for ftp server?

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm using `vsftpd`. I need an `ftp` server for my web server, I can login under my account of course, but I can't do the main thing it's meant for and add/edit/remove files in my var/www directory.

Could someone walk me through the process in creating a new user for just ftp, and allow it to edit anything in that folder?  Or is there an easier way to edit that with another account?

Comment: could You specify what software You use for ftp server?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's VSFTPD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

edit `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and remove `#` from `local_enable=YES`,
`write_enable=YES` and `chroot_list_enable=YES`.

now enter this to terminal `sudo touch /etc/vsftp.chroot_list`

and finally edit `/etc/vsftp.chroot_list` and add one user per line.

Comment: And that will give me access to that folder?

Comment: Ya that didn't solve my problem, I can't access edit/create/or download files in var/www.  That's why i asked this question :|

Comment: User must have permission to read/write/execute in /var/www to do such a things. I suggest reading `man chmod` and `man chown`

Comment: How can I specify the password in this file. Is it username:password pattern or username=password pattern. Please specify.

Comment: have you example how to edit /etc/vsftp.chroot_list. username + password